# How should I handle the case in which a username is already in use?

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli

To practice PHP and MySQL development, I am attempting to create the user registration system for an online chess game.

What are the best practices for:

- How I should handle the (likely) possibility that when a user tries to register, the username he has chosen is already in use, particularly when it comes to function return values? Should I make a separate SELECT query before the INSERT query?
- How to handle varying page titles?
  (`$gPageTitle = '...'; require_once 'bgsheader.php';` is rather ugly)

(An excerpt of the code I have written so far is in the history.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a separate `SELECT` to check whether the username is already in use before attempting to `INSERT`.

More importantly, I would suggest something like the following structure for the script you're writing. It has a strong separation of presentation logic (e.g. HTML) from your other processing (e.g. validation, database, business logic.) This is one important aspect of the model-view-controller paradigm and is generally considered a best-practice.

```
<?php

// The default state of the form is incomplete with no errors.
$title = "Registration";
$form_completed = false;
$errors = array();

// If the user is submitting the form ..
if ($_POST) {

    // Validate the input.
    // This includes checking if the username is taken.
    $errors = validate_registration_form($_POST);

    // If there are no errors.
    if (!count($errors)) {

        // Add the user.
        add_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        // The user has completed.
        $form_completed = true;

        // Optionally you could redirect to another page here.

    } else {

        // Update the page title.
        $title = "Registration, again!"

    }

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Great Site: <?= $title ?></title>
<body>

<?php if ($form_complete): ?>

    <p>Thanks for registering!</p>

<?php else: ?>

    <?php if (count($errors)): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
    <li><?= $error ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing you can do instead of repeating code down near the bottom is this:

```
if( $result === true ) {
    $gPageTitle = 'Registration successful';
    $response = <p>You have successfully registered as ' . htmlspecialchars( $username ) . ' on this site.</p>';
} elseif( $result == 'exists' ) {
    $gPageTitle = 'Username already taken';
    $response = '<p>Someone is already using the username you have chosen. Please try using another one instead.</p>';
} else {
    trigger_error('This should never happen');
}

require_once 'bgsheader.php';
echo $response;
require_once 'bgsfooter.php';
```

Also, you can return false rather than the string 'exists' in the function, not that it makes much difference.

Checking the error number isn't bad, I'm sure that's why it's an included feature.  If you really wanted to do something different, you could check if there already is a user by that name by selecting the username.  If no result exists, then insert the user, otherwise, give the error.

One thing I like to do with error handling on forms is save all the error strings into an array like $error['username'], $error['email'], etc., and then have it run through the error checking on each input individually to set all the error strings, and then have a function that does something like this:

```
function error($field)
{
     global $error;
     if(isset($error[$field]))
     {
          echo $error[$field];
     }
}
```

and then call that after each field in the form to give error reporting on the form.  Of course, the form page must submit to itself, but you could have all the error checking logic in a separate file and do an include if $_POST['whatever'] is set.  If your form is formatted in a table or whatever, you could even do something like `echo '<tr><td class="error">' . $error[$field] . '</td></tr>`, and automatically insert another row directly below the field to hold the error if there is one.

Also, always remember to filter your inputs, even if it should be filtered automatically.  Never pass post info directly into a DB without checking it out.  I'd also suggest using the specific superglobal variable for the action, like $_POST rather than $_REQUEST, because $_REQUEST contains $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIE variables, and someone could feasibly do something strange like submit to the page with ?username=whatever after the page, and then you have both $_POST['username'] and $_GET['username'], and I'm not sure how $_REQUEST would handle that.  Probably would make there be a $_REQUEST['username'][0] and $_REQUEST['username'][1].

Also, a bit about the page titles.  Don't know if you have it set up like this but you can do something like this in your header:

```
$pageTitle = "My Website";
if(isset($gPageTitle))
{
    $pageTitle .= "- $gPageTitle";
}
echo "<title>$pageTitle</title>";
```

Which would make the page load normally with "My Website" as the title, and append "- Username already exists" or whatever for "My Website - Username already exists" as the title when $gPageTitle is set.

Comment: When filtering $_POST input, you can use something like array_map(), which puts each element of an array through a function and maps it to a new array.  So, you have a function that does something like: `function escapestring($input){return mysql_real_escape_string(trim($input));}` and then do `$filteredinput = array_map('escapestring',$_POST);` and you get $filteredinput['username'] $filterinput['password'] etc that have been passed through the function specified in the first argument of array_map.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should get into forms and allow your page to redirect to another page where you have there the 'insert username to database'.
2. Suppose the username entered is in a post variable such as `$_POST['username']`.
3. Have your database check where that username exist:

   ```
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='$_POST['username']'") or die(mysql_error());
   if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
   echo "Username exists.";
   // more code to handle username exist    
   } else {
   // ok here.
   }
   ```

What is basically done is we check if your table already contains an existing username. `mysql_num_rows($res)` will return 0 if no username exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from Mr. Neigyl would require a separate trip to the database, which is not a good idea because it would only add performance overhead to yuor app. 
 I am not a PHP guru, but I know my way around it, although I don't recall the === operator.  == I remember.
 You could pass the function call directly into the IF statement.

```
if (addUser($username, $passwd));
```

I don't see anything wrong with using the $gPageTitle variable, but you will probably have to declare it "global" first and then use namespaces so you can actually access it within the "header.php" because "header.php" will not know how to address this page's variables.
Although I personally don't like messing with namespaces and I would rather call a function from the "header.php" and pass the page title into it

```
  display_title($pgTitle);
```

or

```
  display_title("Registration Successfull");
```

or

```
  $header->display_title("Registration Successfull")
```

if you like OO style better

Let me know if that helps. :)

Comment: Wouldn't have to use namespaces to make the header file recognize the variables from the page it's being included in.  Include includes the file like it is actually written as a part of the page it is included in, thus, the scope of the variables are the same.  He also wouldn't need to declare $gPageTitle global unless it was used within a function.  Also, === is the operator for literal equivalency of type.  So (int)7 is not === to '7', but (int)7 === (int)7.  There's also !== for literal non equivalency so (int)7 !== '7'.

Comment: That is true, but if you happen to run the "header.php" inside a different page that doesn't have the $pageTitle, then you would get an error

Comment: Not if you check whether or not it isset() in the header file before using it.

Comment: Personally I don't like to rely on security checks (which the asker has actually has purpusly omitted in this question) as a primary defence. I think it's better to write a code first that works without the security checks and add security checks later. It is a lot cleaner to separate each function, object and file so they are much more independent from design point of view. But this is a matter of personal preference. :)

Comment: Ah, but you can just as easily turn it around and instead of worrying about whether or not $gPageTitle exists, worry about whether or not the header exists.  If the header itself doesn't exist then calling a function from it will give an error.  So you must check in one place or the other, and it is much easier to check once in the header than every time you call the header from every script that uses the header.  Of course, if the header doesn't exist and you use require, then it will give a fatal error anyway.

Comment: Why would anyone type $require_once ("header.php") if they didn't think it exists?